# Overwrite an array of element sizes when the screen size changes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to build a fullscreen slider. It works great until I resize the screen. I try to update the function that sets the position on resize but this doesn't rewrite the array properly.

```
const container = document.querySelector(".grid-container");
const screens = document.querySelectorAll("#screen");
const screensList = Array.from(screens);
let screenWidth = 0;

// MAYBE ABLE TO USE INSTEAD OF getBoundingClientRect().width
// const observer = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
//   console.log(entries[0].contentRect.width);
// });

// observer.observe(screensList[0]);

let screenPosition = [];

const setScreenPosition = (screenWidth, currentScreen) => {
  screenPosition.push(screenWidth * currentScreen);
};

const setScreenPositionOnResize = (currentScreen) => {
  screenPosition = [];
  setScreenPosition(screenWidth, currentScreen);
};

const setScreenWidth = () => {
  return (screenWidth = screensList[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);
};
setScreenWidth();

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  setScreenWidth();
});

screensList.forEach((scn, i) => {
  const nextBtn = scn.querySelector("#next");
  const backBtn = scn.querySelector("#back");
  const currentScreen = i + 1;
  setScreenPosition(screenWidth, currentScreen);
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    setScreenPositionOnResize(currentScreen);
  });

  const moveFwd = screenPosition[i];
  const moveBk = screenPosition[i - 1] - screenWidth;

  if (nextBtn) {
    nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      container.style.transform = `translateX(-${moveFwd}px)`;
    });
  }

  if (backBtn) {
    backBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      container.style.transform = "translateX(-" + moveBk + "px)";
    });
  }
});
```

This is where I try to rewrite the array with new values.

```
const setScreenPositionOnResize = (currentScreen) => {
  screenPosition = [];
  setScreenPosition(screenWidth, currentScreen);
};
```

This gets called inside an `addEventListener("resize", ...)`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/GaronR/pen/yLRojOe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the problem:

```js
  const moveFwd = screenPosition[i];
  const moveBk = screenPosition[i - 1] - screenWidth;

  if (nextBtn) {
    nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      container.style.transform = `translateX(-${moveFwd}px)`;
    });
  }

  if (backBtn) {
    backBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
      console.log(moveBk, "back");
      container.style.transform = "translateX(-" + moveBk + "px)";
    });
  }
```

This piece of code is ran once per each item of `screensList`, but only at the beggining of the script. When `click` event is dispatched on `nextBtn` or `backBtn` the value `moveFwd` and `moveBk` is what it was at the beggining of the script. It is not being updated.

Next problem is this function:

```js
const setScreenPositionOnResize = (currentScreen) => {
  screenPosition = [];
  setScreenPosition(screenWidth, currentScreen);
};
```

This is called multiple times (once for each of `screensList`) when `resize` event occurs and each time it will clear the `screenPosition`.

Comment: I think there might be more problems. E.g. you are using multiple ids `screen`. This is not good. You should **always** have only one element with the same id. Use class, if you want to select more elements.

Comment: Of course - my bad. ID's should be unique!

I've changed the code and now seems to be working as intended. I've updated the above codepen.